# Get part of a string based on conditions using regex

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

For the life of me, I can't figure out the combination of the regular expression characters to use to parse the part of the string I want. The string is part of a `for` loop giving a line of 400 thousand lines (out of order). The string I have found by matching with the unique number passed by an array `for` loop.

For every string I'm trying to get a date number (such as `20151212` below).

Given the following examples of the strings (pulled from a CSV file with 400k++ lines of strings):

String1:

```
314513,,Jr.,John,Doe,652622,U51523144,,20151212,A,,,,,,,
```

String2:

```
365422,johnd@blankity.com,John,Doe.,Jr,987235,U23481,z725432,20160221,,,,,,,,
```

String3:

```
6231,,,,31248,U51523144,,,CB,,,,,,,
```

There are several complications here...

1. Some names have a "," in them, so it makes it more than 15 commas.
2. We don't know the value of the date, just that it is a date format such as `(get-date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")`

For those who can think of a better way...

We are given two CSV files to match. Algorithmic steps:

- Look in the CSV file 1 for the ID Number (found on the 2nd column)

  ** No ID Numbers will be blank for CSV file 1
- Look in the CSV file 2 and match the ID number from CSV file 1. On this same line, get the date. Once have date, append in 5th column on CSV file 1 with the same row as ID number

  ** Note: CSV file 2 will have $null for some of the values in the ID
  number column

I'm open to suggestions (including using the [Import-Csv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Import-Csv) cmdlet in which I am not to familiar with the flags and syntax of `for` loops with those values yet).

Comment: Do you have a year range?

Comment: if names might have commas can you use a text indicator? (like putting quotes around names like `"St. John"`, `"John-Smith"`, or `"Solo"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
,(19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]),
```

This will match all dates in the given format from 1900 - 2099. It is also specific enough to rule out most other random numbers, although without a larger sample of data, it's impossible to say.

Then in PowerShell:

```
gc data.csv | where { $_ -match ",((19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])),"} | % { $matches[1] }
```

In the PowerShell match we added capturing parenthesis around what we want, and reference the group via the group number in the $matches index.

If you are only interested in matching one line based on a preceding id you could use a lookbehind. For example,

```
 $id=314513; # Or maybe U23481
 gc c:\temp\reg.txt | where { $_ -match "(?<=$id.*),((19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])),"} | % { $matches[1] }
```

Comment: well It works for sure, thanks. But it returns only a bool value. I'm trying to say something like `$value = $string1 -match ,(19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]),`. In this case, `$value` is equal to true, when I need it to hold the [string]$date. Any suggestions??

Comment: updated the answer assuming you were using a csv file, although you could pipe any string into it

Comment: ah i got it... `[regex]$regex = ",(19|20)[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]),"`, next... `$date = $regex.Matches($string) | ForEach-Object ($_.value)`, next... remove the "," `$string = $string -replace ",",""` and finally `$string` is the value of the date. Yay, thanks swestner, google, and stackOverflow <3

Comment: Ah I just read your updated answer, maybe that is better (less verbos)

Comment: Actually that last line in your answer code didn't work for me. It assigns all values of the dates column instead of just the one from the string. So for now, i'll just use what I wrote above these two comments... Thanks for leading me on the right path though :)

Comment: I'm happy your happy, but not knowing what you mean, and feeling like the answer is incomplete is making my ocd kick in. Care to explain?

Comment: Sure, when assigning that last line to a variable or exporting the data, it gives every date in the file (meaning 400,000 dates). I only needed 1 date where the same row of the ID Number was. Think nested for loop.